# cloud functions notifications for android

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, promise, google-cloud-functions

I was trying to send notifications to multiple users with cloud functions of firebase for an android app

Here is what I did.

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/notifications/messages/{pushId}')
  .onWrite(event => {
    const message = event.data.current.val();
    const senderUid = message.userId;
    const groupId = message.groupId;
    const promises = [];


    const getInstanceGroupUsers = admin.database().ref(`/groups/${groupId}/users`).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        snapshot.forEach((child) => {
          var receiverUid = child.key;

          console.log(receiverUid);

          if (senderUid == receiverUid) {
            //if sender is receiver, don't send notification
            promises.push(event.data.current.ref.remove());
            return Promise.all(promises);
          }

          const getInstanceIdPromise = admin.database().ref(`/users/${receiverUid}/message_token`).once('value');
          const getReceiverUidPromise = admin.auth().getUser(receiverUid);
          return Promise.all([getInstanceIdPromise, getReceiverUidPromise]).then(results => {
            const instanceId = results[0].val();
            const receiver = results[1];
            console.log('notifying ' + receiverUid + ' about ' + message.body + ' from ' + senderUid);

            const payload = {
              notification: {
                title: receiver.displayName,
                body: message.message,
                icon: receiver.photoURL
              }
            };

            admin.messaging().sendToDevice(instanceId, payload)
              .then(function(response) {
                console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
              })
              .catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Error sending message:", error);
              });
          });

        });
      }
    });

  });
```

I have never code in JS before and never used cloud functions but what I'm trying to do here is to get the message's groupeId from the node `/notifications/messages/{pushId}` then make a loop over all users of the group for sending notifications.

I don't know if I'm doing it right but those are the errors I get:

> 22:14  error    Each then() should return a value or throw 
>   promise/always-return
>
> 28:34  error    Expected '===' and instead saw '=='         eqeqeq
>
> 36:30  warning  Avoid nesting promises
>   promise/no-nesting
>
> 36:94  error    Each then() should return a value or throw 
>   promise/always-return
>
> 49:27  warning  Avoid nesting promises
>   promise/no-nesting
>
> 49:27  warning  Avoid nesting promises
>   promise/no-nesting
>
> 50:37  warning  Unexpected function expression
>   prefer-arrow-callback
>
> 50:37  error    Each then() should return a value or throw 
>   promise/always-return
>
> 53:38  warning  Unexpected function expression
>   prefer-arrow-callback

Any kind of help will be welcome!

Comment: the errors actually tell you what the problem is. Which ones don't you understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to get rid of the ERRORS and most of the warnings

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/notifications/messages/{pushId}').onWrite(event => {
    const message = event.data.current.val();
    const senderUid = message.userId;
    const groupId = message.groupId;
    const promises = [];


    const getInstanceGroupUsers = admin.database().ref(`/groups/${groupId}/users`).once('value')
    .then((snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            snapshot.forEach((child) => {
                var receiverUid = child.key;

                console.log(receiverUid);
                //*** use === instead of ==
                if (senderUid === receiverUid) {
                    //if sender is receiver, don't send notification
                    promises.push(event.data.current.ref.remove());
                    return Promise.all(promises);
                }

                const getInstanceIdPromise = admin.database().ref(`/users/${receiverUid}/message_token`).once('value');
                const getReceiverUidPromise = admin.auth().getUser(receiverUid);
                return Promise.all([getInstanceIdPromise, getReceiverUidPromise])
                .then(results => {
                    const instanceId = results[0].val();
                    const receiver = results[1];
                    console.log('notifying ' + receiverUid + ' about ' + message.body + ' from ' + senderUid);

                    const payload = {
                        notification: {
                            title: receiver.displayName,
                            body: message.message,
                            icon: receiver.photoURL
                        }
                    };
                    //*** added return, so this .then returns a something as required
                    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(instanceId, payload);
                }) //*** avoid nesting promises, 
                //*** use arrow functions as "prefered" and a return value (the return is implied)
                .then((response) => console.log("Successfully sent message:", response))
                .catch((error) => console.log("Error sending message:", error));
            });
        } 
        //*** now this .then returns something
        return undefined;
    });
});
```

See comments marked `//***`

The only warning left is one of the nested promises warnings - because the logic is unfathomable regarding the code in

```
if (senderUid === receiverUid) {
```

why are you returning Promise.all there?

and the other Promise.all is hard to move, again, because I don't understand what your code is trying to achieve inside the `snapshot.forEach`

But the **errors** should be dealt with now

Comment: I saw an example for sending notification in a simple app of messaging between 2 users, and i try to adapted it for my firebase database witch was a way more complicated, the thing is i just started development in java android this year and i've never seen javascript before. I was trying to send notification to a group of specific users. But i guess I did it the wrong way.   
but i'm trying to understand what you did there and see if it works
thanks a lot 
NB: sorry for my english !!!